# What's the purpose of separate navbar and navbar-inner classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter bootstrap's starter-template.html, the navbar is written as

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if I change the markup to

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

everything seems to work fine and there's no discernible visual differences as far as I can tell. What's the reason to have separate `navbar` and `navbar-inner` classes associated with two divs? Why not just have a `navbar` class that combines styles of both?

Comment: I believe it's for browser compatibility and responsive design.

Comment: Just checked, if I have a single div with both navbar and navbar-inner classes, the responsive navbar still seems to work fine. (Only tested in chrome though)

Answer (score 7):

It makes the stucture of your html document more clear and readable. The .navbar class sets the position (and has a default display inline) while the navbar-inner class wraps the content of this container (display table).
Your .navbar can contain more as one blocks like navbar-inner.

In your hierarchical DOM-structure .navbar has the same level as the .container(fluid) divs:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand, extra div when no extra div is needed doesn't seem like clear and reabable to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is way old but I had the same question recently. I think the purpose is cosmetic.

I've noticed that .navbar-inner has a linear gradient background. With multiple rows of .navbar-inner, each nav row is more clearly defined for the end user.

For each type of navbar style, .navbar-inner has different means of visually delineating it's content.